# Comment Text to wrap to new row in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel Spreadsheet with a comments section that is comprised of 4 rows. The comment section of the Row is made up of the merged cells `A51:AD51`, `A52:AD52`, `A53:AD53`, and `A54:AD54`. I want the user of the speadsheet to type their whole comment into the first row and then when they hit Enter to have the comment broken up to fit as best possible in each of the four rows and the remaining overflow, if any, to be on the last line. For example:

[image: Comment Pre Wrapping]

Would then become:

[image]

Things I have tried:

- Measuring the pixel length of the text using `GetTextExtentPoint32` and then comparing this length to the merged cell length. I had to eventually hard code the length of the column because I couldn't properly work out an accurate pixel length of the merged cells. This has worked the best so far but really doesn't seem like a good solution - I particularly don't like the hard coding.
- I also tried measuring the column width of the cell, calling `AutoFit` and then comparing the new width with the original width, but for reason this doesn't seem to be working because the autofit width is the same as the current width even though the text definitely doesn't fit into the cell. This might have to do with the cells being merged, but I am not sure.

What the best way to work out whether the text fits into the merged cell or not? Once I have that, I can then break it up easily enough, it just determining if it fits or not.

Comment: why merging all 4 rows and setting word wrap is not an option?

Comment: @user3964075 It has been proposed and it would certainly be the simplest option, but the users don't like the look and feel. They want it over the 4 rows.

Comment: autofit doesn't work if the cells are merged - how about this: copy cell value somewhere else to a single cell  - hidden sheet for example - then call autofit?

Comment: @user3964075 how do I ensure the single cell is of the same width as the merged cell?

Comment: calculate the sum of A:AD widths

Answer (score 0):

- Use a fixed width font.
- Calculate the length of the string `x = Len(Range("A51").Value)`
- Divide x by 4 to get characters per line `y = x / 4`
- Multiply the characters per line by the set pixel width of the font character. `z = y * pixelwidth`
- Set the width of your column to match that pixel width `Range.ColumnWidth`
- Use `Mid()` with characters per line (`y`) to break up the string.

I'll work on looking at some total code for this, but this should get you on the right track.